# Update with latest data from git

Tags: git, smartgit

I am using smartgit for accessing files from git. I tried PULL and FETCH option to update. But no change. I don't know what to do?

Comment: And what do you expect to change?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @SarathSRajendran : i need to commit updated files to fork. but each time i am commiting it keep appends to my previous commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of committing to the same branch (or branching from the same head) is that if there is a problem in one pull request, we cannot merge the pull requests after that since the commits exists in all the later pull requests. My suggestion is to create a branch for every new issue fix:

To do so you should first set the upstream in your system (only once)

```
git remote add upstream
```

make sure your origin is set to your own fork:`git remote -v`. After that for each new fix do the following:

```
1-git checkout -b  <new branch related to pull request>
2- git fetch upstream
3- git reset --hard upstream/<branch>
4- commit to origin
5- make pull request
6- go to 1 for the next issue to fix
```

This is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Are you pushing your changes to your origin server?  This is the only way you are going to get your changes to a remote server.

[image: Push button in SmartGit]

Answer (score 0):

I get it. Its because of the extra -b in the command.